# List compehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have in my folder 500 images(jpeg). How can I choose all images with list comprehension?

Example

```
path="D/my folder"

path_1=[item for item in path (*.jpeg)]
```

Where do I mistake?

Comment: `path (*.jpeg)` is not valid Python syntax. You'e looking for the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/glob.html#module-glob)

Comment: How can I write a valid syntax?

Comment: Use `glob`: `path_1 = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.jpeg')` https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: What is the problem? You haven't said what the issue actually is, and the title is not descriptive at all, I'm voting to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile
mypath = r"somepath"
onlyjpeg = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if f.endswith('.jpeg')]
print(onlyjpeg)
```